# Save Config Button is not Working in Magento Admin

Tags: configuration, magento-1.9

I want to enable COD and Paypal payment option but save config button is not working in System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods.

I am getting success message like "**The configuration has been saved.**" But configuration does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my hosting company, we tracked this down to being caused by suhosin, they increased the following suhosin limits in the php.ini file for my server which resolved the issue:

```
max_input_vars = 1000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000
```

It would also help to other who googling this same issue.